# How does np.argmax(axis=0) work on 3D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

I am stuck at, as to how does np.argmax(arr, axis=0) work? I know how np.argmax(axis=0) works on 2D arrays. But this 3D one has really confused me.

**My Code:**

```
   arr = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                   [ 4,  5,  6],
                   [ 7,  8,  9],
                   [10, 11, 12]],
                   
                   [[13, 14, 15],
                   [16, 17, 18],
                   [19, 20, 21],
                   [22, 23, 24]],
                   
                   [[25, 26, 27],
                   [28, 29, 30],
                   [31, 32, 33],
                   [34, 35, 36]]])
```

**Operation:**

```
np.argmax(arr, axis = 0)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

FYI - I do know how np.argmax(axis=0) works on 2D arrays. But this 3D one has really confused me.

Comment: Lets call the dimensions 'plane', 'row', 'col'.  For each row and col, the largest value is in the last (2) plane.  Things could be clearer it the dimensions differed, e.g. (4,3,2), and values were a bit more mixed.  Still, using the result of this `argmax` isn't easy.

Comment: @hpaul Alright, that 'plane', 'row', 'col' meaning makes sense to me. But then I'm getting really confused with more dimensions, [like it's visualised here](https://beerensahu.wordpress.com/2018/03/21/pytorch-tutorial-lesson-1-tensor/). Is it a better idea to keep spatial images in mind while working with 4,5,6 or more dimensions, or is it better to use a specific `numpy` symbolism automatically with no geometric embodiments?

Comment: One example of 4d would be `[image, width, height, color]` for a batch of color images.  But to `numpy` those names don't matter; they are all just axes.  The names are application specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand better what is `axis=0` here. It can be interpreted as height level of rectangle. So your output shows different levels of that rectangle:

```
   level 0       level 1       level 2
[ 1,  2,  3]  [13, 14, 15]  [16, 17, 18]
[ 4,  5,  6]  [16, 17, 18]  [19, 20, 21]
[ 7,  8,  9]  [19, 20, 21]  [22, 23, 24]
[10, 11, 12]  [22, 23, 24]  [25, 16, 27]
```

Then `argmax` describes indices of levels at which `max` values are attained. They are:

```
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21]
[22, 23, 24]
[25, 16, 27]
```

It's definitely the upmost level (number 2) for any of these cells
so argmax of every cell is assigned to 2.

Comment: what an explanation. Hats Off to you man! I had been struggling with it from past 2 days.

Comment: But what if I have level 0 only? that means: 

np.random.seed(0) -------------------------------------------------

randint_array_2 = np.random.randint(36, size=(1,2,5))

Comment: This one gives me all zeros in output. Does is mean that it is comparing with an invisible level here?

Comment: This mean that you have only one level to pick from, its level number 0. You would rather try to imagine visual image of 3 dimensions as I have mentioned [here](https://beerensahu.wordpress.com/2018/03/21/pytorch-tutorial-lesson-1-tensor/) before.

Comment: Dimensions (1,2,5) can be called 'plane', 'row', 'col' as @hpaul pointed out before as well, it tells how many planes, rows and cols are in 3D image of array.

Comment: Yup, I just saw those diagrams. That is understandable. So does this mean that it is comparing level 0 with itself? thus, the results are showing all zeros?

Comment: yes, it iis a case where list of levels is [0]. In before mentioned example levels could be listed as [0, 1, 2]. And you were deciding which of these levels contains maximum value for each cell of projection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221025/discussion-between-web-development-labs-and-mathfux).